# g++ compiler can't compile fully defined types

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use static instance of the struct in the same struct but g++ compiler tells me that:

```
C:\Temp\cs2cpp_tries\test\test.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Static<Test<int> >':
C:\Temp\cs2cpp_tries\test\test.cpp:16:19:   required from 'struct Test<int>'
C:\Temp\cs2cpp_tries\test\test.cpp:20:12:   required from here
C:\Temp\cs2cpp_tries\test\test.cpp:6:4: error: 'Static<T>::t' has incomplete type
  T t;
    ^
C:\Temp\cs2cpp_tries\test\test.cpp:10:8: note: declaration of 'struct Test<int>'
 struct Test
        ^~~~
```

Here is the code example. You can see that types are defined but g++ still does not like it.

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct Static
{
    T t;
};

template < typename T >
struct Test
{
    static Static<Test<T>> t;
};

template < typename T >
Static< Test<T> > Test<T>::t;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    Test<int> t;
    return 0;
}
```

But if you remove `template < typename T >` from test class and code becomes fully compilable

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct Static
{
    T t;
};

struct Test
{
    static Static<Test> t;
};

Static< Test > Test::t;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    Test t;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a reference or pointer type.

Comment: Yes, it cannot be instatiated before it's completely defined.

Comment: well just remove "template < typename T >" from test class and it will be fully compiled.  Here is example:  `#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct Static
{
 T t;
};

struct Test
{
 static Static<Test> t;
};

Static< Test > Test::t;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 Test t;
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Looks like an gcc bug to me. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/4scShZ)

Comment: I agree with you. I don't see any reason not to compile the code

Comment: What's weird is the gcc error message *"Static<T>::t' has incomplete type"*, but there is no `Static<T>` in sight

Comment: T in Static<T> is template parameter

Comment: [Both Clang and Microsoft’s compiler can compile this just fine](https://godbolt.org/g/SHz5tz), although Microsoft still gives warnings for unused variables even when I add the C++17 `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute. I think this is a G++ bug.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a gcc bug, from [[class.static]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#data-2)

> The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv void.

So regardless whether `Test<T>` or `Static<Test<T>>` has complete type, the declaration should be allowed.

From [[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp)

> the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type

---

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions, [...] static data members [...]

Means when we first use `Test<int>` to declare a variable, `Test<int>` is required to be a completely-defined type, so `Test<int>` is implicitly instantiated, but `Static<Test<int>>` isn't required to be a completely-defined object type since it is still only declared.

Funnily enough, gcc compiles this just fine

```
template<typename>
struct Static;

template<typename T>
struct Test
{
    static Static<Test<T>> t;
};

template<typename T>
Static<Test<T>> Test<T>::t;

Test<int> t;
//auto u = t.t;  // error, now requires a completely-defined type
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/BH2N9h)

Even though `Static` isn't even defined, `Test::t` never needed to be a completely-defined type.

Comment: if you put Static declaration into Test one the code will be compilable :)

Comment: @Alexander77 I have no idea what is causing gcc to do what its doing, but its error message is both mystifying and doesn't line up with the quotes above.

Comment: You're skipping a layer here; the code isn't **just** using types; it's using templates, and talking about incomplete **types** doesn't address incomplete **templates**.

Comment: @PasserBy -- to be clear, I'm not saying that your conclusion is wrong. I haven't dug into it, and don't have the energy for that now.

Comment: can we consider that the code is fully compilable by microsoft c++ compiler and thus types and templates are complete?